# Error when get data from sqlite display in gridview android

Tags: android, gridview, android-sqlite, simplecursoradapter, custom-adapter

I want to retrieve the data from `SQLite` and display in `GridView`, but it shown errors. I hope someone can help me on this.

Thanks in advance.

#### **DatabaseHandler.java**

```
// Getting All icons
public List<Icon> getAllIcons() {
    List<Icon> iconList = new ArrayList<Icon>();
    // Select All Query
    String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_CATALOG;
 
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
 
    // looping through all rows and adding to list
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            Icon icon = new Icon();
            icon.setID(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)));
            icon.setName(cursor.getString(1));
            icon.setIconpath(cursor.getString(2));
            // Adding contact to list
            iconList.add(icon);
        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }
 
    // return contact list
    return iconList;
}
```

#### **IconListAdapter.java**

```
public class IconListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    Context context;
    //List<Icon> iconList;
    List<Icon> iconList = new ArrayList<Icon>();

    public IconListAdapter(Context context, List<Icon> list) {
        this.context = context;
        iconList = list;
    }
    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return iconList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return iconList.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup arg2) {
        Icon icon = iconList.get(position);

        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.screen_list, null);
        }

        TextView iconname = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.iconname);
        iconname.setText(icon.getName());
        TextView id = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.id);
        id.setText(icon.getID());
        
        return convertView;
    }
}
```

#### **DisplayDatabaseActivity.java**

```
public class DisplayDatabaseActivity extends Activity {

    DatabaseHandler databasehandler;
    GridView gridView;

    //ArrayList<Icon> iconList = new ArrayList<Icon>();
    // List<Icon> iconList = new ArrayList<Icon>();
    IconListAdapter iconlistadapter;
    //SimpleAdapter simpleadapter;
    //ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> iconsList;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_display_database);

        databasehandler = new DatabaseHandler(this);
        //databasehandler.getAllIcons();

        //List<Icon> iconList = new ArrayList<Icon>();
        // List <Icon> iconList = databasehandler.getAllIcons();
        //databasehandler.getAllIcons();

        Log.d("Reading: ", "Reading all contacts.."); 
        List <Icon> iconList = databasehandler.getAllIcons();
        for (Icon cn : iconList) {
            String log = "ID:" + cn.getID() + " Name: " + cn.getName() + " ,Image: " +                 cn.getIconpath();

            // Writing Contacts to log
            Log.d("Result: ", log);
        } 

        gridView = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridView1);

        iconlistadapter=new IconListAdapter(DisplayDatabaseActivity.this,iconList);        
        gridView.setAdapter(iconlistadapter);
    }
}
```

#### **Logcat Error:**

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x1
    at android.content.res.Resources.getText(Resources.java:247)
    at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3428)
    atcom.megamobile.digital_catalog.IconListAdapter.getView(IconListAdapter.java:56)
    at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2033)
    at android.widget.GridView.onMeasure(GridView.java:1026)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:12603)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4677)
```

Comment: May you are not getting `TextView` using `convertView`